# Cannot delete data laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

hello friends I want to ask,
why the data is not deleted? I have clicked on it but in the database it is not deleted.
My php version 8

migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_akun', function (Blueprint $table) {           
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama_role')->unique();
            $table->string('roles');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

controller in function destroy

```
public function destroy(ManageROle $manageROle)
    {
        $manageROle->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

models

```
class ManageROle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "role_akun";
    protected $fillable = ['id','nama_role','roles'];

}
```

blade layout

```
<form action="{{ route('manage_role.destroy',$roles->id) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
```

i used route resource

```
Route::resource('manage_role', ManageRoleController::class);
```

please help me :(

Comment: Make sure that your key is `$manageROle`, you can get it by `php artisan route:list` also you need to change this (Laravel 8) `{{ route('manage_role.destroy', ['manageROle' => $roles->id]) }}`

Comment: @EsTeAa https://ibb.co/yq6Xc9M yes sir, is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route :

```
{{ route('manage_role.destroy', ['manage_role' => $roles->id]) }}
```

And your controller :

```
public function destroy(ManageROle $manage_role)
{
    $manage_role->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```